# Number precision error in C

Tags: c, precision, floating-point-precision

Here is a code I wrote:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    double num;
    int tmp;
    printf("enter a number!\n");
    scanf("%lf",&num);
    tmp=num*10000;
    printf(" temp=%d\n",tmp);

    return 0; 
}
```

When I enter the number 1441.1441 the result i'm getting is 14411440 instead of 
14411441 which is obviously the correct result after multiplying my input number by 10000. Can someone help me figure out this problem?

Comment: I get 14411441.  What OS are you using? Is it 32 bit?

Comment: What happens if you change `tmp` to be a `double` and also change `10000` to `10000.0`?

Comment: the same problem is reproduced for me. I m using linux on 32 bit system

Comment: This is such a FAQ... [read this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html).

Comment: i tried 10000.0 and its not working too..

Comment: i am using windows 7 64 bit.. and i've tried in windows 8 32 bits also.. same result..  Lundin could you be more precise?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since the vast majority of real numbers cannot actually be represented exactly, you'll probably find that `1441.1441` is actually stored as something like `1441.14409999_blah_blah_blah`. You can find that out by inserting:

```
printf ("%.50lf\n", num);
```

immediately after the `scanf` and seeing (trailing zeroes removed):

```
1441.14409999999998035491444170475006103515625
```

Now that's actually the correct (ie, closest) value based on your input. The next highest number from there gives you:

```
1441.144100000000207728589884936809539794921875
```

The error with the first value is:

```
0.00000000000001964508555829524993896484375
               ^ ~ 2 x 10^-14
```

while the error with the second is:

```
0.000000000000207728589884936809539794921875
              ^ ~ 2 x 10^-13
```

and you can see the latter error is about 10 times as much.

When you multiply that by `10000` and try to shoehorn it into an `int`, it gets rounded *down* (truncated). That's because the (C11) standard has this to say in `6.3.1.4`:

> When a finite value of real floating type is converted to an integer type other than _Bool, the fractional part is discarded (i.e., the value is truncated toward zero).

One thing you can try is to change your shoehorning line into:

```
tmp = num * 10000 + 0.5;
```

which effectively turns the truncation into a rounding operation. I *think* that will work for all cases but you may want to test it (and keep an eye on it) just in case.

Comment: he input the float number. and not is given from an arithmetic operation

Comment: if you change tmp to float you will get the following result: `temp=14411441.000000`

Comment: @Mohamed KALLEL: a number that can't be represented exactly can't be represented exactly, whatever the method you used to "input" it.

Comment: +1, and if you ever have a spare couple of hours, I highly advise a read of [this document](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html), which explains everything you wanted to know, and a lot that you didn't, about floating pointer representations.

Comment: Since some people are getting different results: the difference has to be in scanf. Apparently some implementations will round up to the higher adjacent double value (or to the nearest), and some will round down to the lower one.

Comment: @Medo42 This information is the most insightful of the whole question, and I wish it appeared prominently in an answer instead of jut in a comment.

Comment: I'm not sure why you mention floats. These variables are double rather than single precision, and have more than enough precision bits to represent every 32-bit value.

Comment: @Medo42 Another explanation is that the multiplication is performed at greater precision than `double` on some systems, but not on others. If you multiply at `double` precision, the result is exactly 14411441.

Answer (score 1):

For the general principle, [paxdiablo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13525471/1011995) contains the relevant parts. Most terminating decimal fractions cannot be exactly represented as binary floating point numbers, hence the value of the floating point variable is a little smaller or larger than the mathematical value of the number representation in the given string, so when you want to get the appropriate integer value after scaling, you should round and not truncate.

But in the specific example here, we have a different scenario. The closest IEEE754 double precision (64-bit binary) value to 1441.1441 is

```
1441.14409999999998035491444170475006103515625
```

which is indeed a little smaller than 1441.1441. But if that value is multiplied with 10000 as an IEEE754 double precision value, the result is exactly

```
14411441
```

What happens here is that, as is allowed per 5.2.4.2.2 paragraph 9

> Except for assignment and cast (which remove all extra range and precision), the values yielded by operators with floating operands and values subject to the usual arithmetic conversions and of floating constants **are evaluated to a format whose range and precision may be greater than required by the type**.

(emphasis mine), the product is evaluated with a greater precision than required by the type (probably the x87 80-bit format), yielding a slightly smaller value, and when the result of the multiplication is converted to `int`, the fractional part is discarded, and you get 14411440.

```
scanf("%lf",&num);
```

The value is stored in `num`, so it must have exactly the precision of `double`.

```
tmp=num*10000;
```

The product `num * 10000` is neither stored nor cast to `double`, so it may have greater precision, resulting in a smaller or larger value than the closest `double` value. That value is then truncated to obtain the `int`.

If you stored the product in a `double` variable

```
num *= 10000;
tmp = num;
```

or cast it to `double` before converting to `int`,

```
tmp = (double)(num * 10000);
```

you ought to get the result 14411441 for the input `1441.1441` (but note that not all compilers always honour the requirement of converting to the exact required precision when casting or storing - violating the standard - so there's no guarantee that that will produce 14411441 with all optimisation settings).

Since many 64-bit platforms perform floating-point arithmetic using SSE instructions rather than the x87 coprocessor, the observed behaviour is less likely to appear on 64-bit systems than on 32-bit systems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to make it round like that:

```
float a = 3.14;

int i = (int)(a+0.5);
```

In your case:

```
 double num;
 int tmp;
 printf("enter a number!\n");
 scanf("%lf",&num);
 tmp=(int)(num*10000 + 0.5);
 printf(" temp=%d\n",tmp);
```

Answer (score -4):

It looks like scanf is using float precision inside scanf. I breifly checked that 1441.1441 is represented in float as 1441.1440.
In genereal you shouldn't rely on precision in floating point operations.

Comment: I dont think it is the case. It will be a violation of the contract of `%lf`.

Comment: I ckecked it in my java project.

Comment: System.out.println((float)1441.1441); prints 1441.144